# Double integration over function with absolute values

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, absolute-value

I have having difficulty in how to solve the following double integral problem involving absolute values and the assumption that $\alpha > 1$:

$\iint_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+|x|^\alpha} \frac{1}{1+|y|^\alpha} \frac{1}{1+|x-y|^\alpha} \,dx\,dy$

Any tips on how to calculate the above integration is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: get rid of the absolute values by splitting the plane into different regions. For example, $\int_{-1}^1 |x| dx=\int_{-1}^0 -x dx+\int_{0}^1 x dx$.

Comment: Could you please split the actual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double integral can be split into several integrals involving only trigonometric functions. But these integrals cannot be expressed in terms of a finite number of standard functions. So, it is doubtful that a closed form could be obtained to express the double integral :

[image]